# Find maximum values in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the maximum values in a SQL Server query starting from the following query

```
SELECT D.CANTON, D.FECHA, COUNT(D.FECHA) AS FRECUENCIA
FROM [dbo].[DETENCION] D
GROUP BY D.CANTON, D.FECHA
ORDER BY FRECUENCIA DESC
```

Running the query I get the following output:

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cntnI.png)

Now what I need is to find the cities (`CANTON`) that have the highest frequency (`FRECUENCIA`) of dates.

Can someone give me any help? Please

Comment: Sample data and expected results (all as text not images) would help immensely. Do you not just want `TOP (1)`?

Comment: No, I am finding the maximum frequency values for each city with its respective date and highest frequency.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a top-1-per-group answer `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.CANTON ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: I'd use MAX over partition, in case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want -

```
WITH J
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.FECHA ORDER BY R.FRECUENCIA DESC) AS rn
         , R.CANTON
         , R.FECHA
         , R.FRECUENCIA
    FROM
    (
        SELECT D.CANTON
             , D.FECHA
             , COUNT(D.FECHA) AS FRECUENCIA
        FROM dbo.DETENCION AS D
        GROUP BY D.CANTON
               , D.FECHA
    ) AS R
)
SELECT J.CANTON
     , J.FECHA
     , J.FRECUENCIA
FROM J
WHERE J.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Will this work for ties?

Comment: @jarlh Just change to `DENSE_RANK`. This does not need the innermost subquery, it can be done on two levels only